# WiFi 8812au does not work on Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel 5.0.0-36

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I have bought a TP link rtl8812au based wifi module.
followed the instructions and installed drivers I think they were 4.2.2 the wifi was running but it did not find and anything. when running lshw -c network it the status was "DISABLED".
I tried multiple versions and fixes and none worked came across what seems to be the latest one:
https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au
followed the instructions everything compiled and installed. To test I have configured the LED in /etc/modprobe.d/8812au.conf
options 8812au rtw_led_enable=1

```
sudo modinfo 8812au
```

output

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8812au.ko
version:        v5.2.20.2_28373.20180619
...
parm:           rtw_en_gro:int
parm:           rtw_iqk_fw_offload:int
parm:           rtw_led_enable:Enable status LED (int)
```

So the driver loaded and read the config. However 
no wireless network,

```
lshw -c network does not show the wifi

kernel version is 5.0.0-36
```

Comment: Is 8812au correct for your device? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The device is the first one in the list. It does not show any name/manufacturer

Comment: Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2357:0115  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c24c Logitech, Inc. G400s Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: the device I bought is a TP Link AC1300 (Archer T4U) which is listed as working with Linux and based on the rtl2212au chipset.

Comment: went to the web site today and it looks like TP Link does not list a chipset for this device.

Comment: sudo usb-devices

Comment: '''
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=06 Cnt=01 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2357 ProdID=0115 Rev=02.10
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11ac NIC
S:  SerialNumber=123456
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 5 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
'''

Comment: The serial number 123456 looks very suspicious

Answer (score 0):

Use this repo and follow the instructions

https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

```
//step 1
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au
//step 2
make all or make
//step 3
sudo make install
//step 4
sudo mod probe 88XXau
```

That's it your wifi will be up :)

PS: make sure that you remove any driver's which you installed previously.

Comment: Sorry, 8812au is not correct for his 2357:0115 device.

Comment: oh sorry for that, as he was trying 8812au I just suggested him the driver.

Answer (score 0):

The TP-Link wireless devices come in several versions; some earlier versions are driven by *8812au*. Your 2357:0115 device is driven by *88x2bu*. You can install it with the following steps. With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, do:

```
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Answer (score 0):

thank you both,
Yes the chip set is 88x2bu for TPLink Archer T4U V3 it was 8812au for V1 and V2
The driver on the TP Link website did not compile on 18.04 so downloaded the same one from here
https://github.com/its-izhar/rtl88x2bu-driver/pull/4/files

applied all the changes in the pull request (may get merged in the future) and:

```
make clean
make
sudo cp ./88x2bu.ko /lib/modules/(uname -r)/kernel/net/wireless
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe 88x2bu.ko
the last command did not work
disabled secure boot in the BIOS
sudo modprobe 88x2bu.ko

rebooted and worked.
```

One think I have noticed is that in the same spot I plug the wifi in a windows system I get better signal for a network (4 bars out of 5) while plugging it in Linux gives me barely one for the same network. (a public one) I checked and they use different channels. So obviously the linux/ubuntu scan algorithm probably takes the first one found whilst the windows one takes the strongest. something to improve.

Comment: That should be the subject of a new question since it is a new issue. I think we can solve it easily.